# Equality of a function and Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, special-functions, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

Does the following function have a Taylor series of the form given below:

$$\frac{1}{(1+(\eta z)^n)^p} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^i\Gamma(p+i)\eta^{in}}{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(i+1)}\right)z^{in}?$$

If yes, are there any further simplification(s) or an easier and proper form?

CODE:

clc; clear all; close all; format long

n=4.2; p=0.75; eta= 10.5; z=0.05; numTaylorTerms=10;

Approx=0;

for i=0:1:numTaylorTerms

```
 Approx=Approx+((-1)^(i)*gamma(p+i)/(gamma(p)*gamma(i+1)))*(eta*z)^(i*n);
```

end

Approx

Exact=1/(1+(eta*z)^n)^p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go with Newtons binomial series,

$$(1+x^n)^{-p}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{-p}{i} x^{in}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{p+i-1}{p-1}(-1)^ix^{in}$$

it converges to the value on the left side for $|x|<1$.

---

For the case $|x|>1$ use the same series in $x^{-1}$, i.e., after the transformation

$$(1+x^n)^{-p}=x^{-np}(1+x^{-n})^{-p}=x^{-np}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{-p}{i} x^{-in}$$

---

One can use the binomial identities (see also the other answer)

$$\tbinom{-p}{i}=\frac{-p(-p-1)...(-p-i+1)}{i!}=(-1)^i\tbinom{p+i-1}{i}=(-1)^i\tbinom{p+i-1}{p-1}$$

to get binomials of positive numbers.

Comment: is there anyway to treat other values of |x|>1?

Comment: Yes, this would result in a Laurent series, I'll add this.

Comment: yes please because I am interested in large values of z :)

Comment: How can I write \binom{-p}{i} in MATLAB, the N Choose K will not work since the values of "-p" is not a "positive" integer...is there any other way?

Comment: Either using the gamma functions or as above, $\tbinom{-p}{i}=(-1)^i\tbinom{p+i-1}{i}=(-1)^i\tbinom{p+i-1}{p-1}$.

Comment: I can't thank you enough :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks too complicated and unfamiliar but it is exactly the opposite: It is simply the binomial expnasion for negative exponent:
$$
(1+x)^{-m}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{-m}{i}x^{i},
$$
which is valid for $|x|<1$.

In particular,
$$
\binom{-m}{i}=\frac{(-m)(-m-1)\cdots(-m-i+1)}{i!}=(-1)^i\frac{m(m+1)\cdots(m+i-1)}{i!}
=(-1)^i\frac{\Gamma(m+i)}{\Gamma(i+1)\Gamma(m)},
$$ 
and hence
$$
(1+x)^{-m}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i\frac{\Gamma(m+i)}{\Gamma(i+1)\Gamma(m)}x^{i},
$$
Set $m=p$ and $x=(\eta z)^n$ and obtain:
$$
\frac{1}{\big(1+(\eta z)^n\big)^p}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i\frac{\Gamma(p+i)}{\Gamma(i+1)\Gamma(p)}(\eta z)^{ni}.
$$

Comment: excellent...but then can you please have a look at my matlab code? Matlab first 9 terms approximation are not similar to the exact value of the expression for different cases of the parameters n,p and eta at different values of z.

Please see the code in the question edit.

Comment: Sorry, a little mistake: $\Gamma(p+i+1)$ should be replaced by $\Gamma(p+i)$.

Comment: It did not work, even if I do the replacement you suggested. Can you please re-check it.

Comment: $i$ starts for $0$, not from $1$.

Comment: please see my edited code...this approximation works for small values of z, but not for large ones, even if I increase the number of taylor series terms...is there any specific reason?

Comment: I run all these in my MacBookRetina15 (2013) with MATLAB 2013a, and both numbers agree. So your code looks fine.

Comment: try to change z to some other value, for example 10...the results will be different